# Unity not rendering animation in playmode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

My door animation plays all fine in Editor, but in playmode, it seems not to render, but the collisions seem to work fine. [Here's what happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rtsz.gif)

The Animator is set up [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e73AN.png)

The Animation the game should show consists of just moving two children objects, for more info. What did I do wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It pretty much seems like your objects are marked as [**static**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html) and therefore the meshes get combined into a single static scene mesh.

> Many systems in Unity can precompute information about static GameObjects in the Editor. **Because the GameObjects do not move**, the results of these calculations are still valid at runtime. This means that Unity can save on runtime calculations, and potentially improve performance.

As the name **static** already suggests: These objects are static and can not be moved by the Animator.